# Are code contracts guaranteed to be evaluated before chained constructors are called?

Tags: c#, code-contracts, constructor-chaining

Before I started using Code Contracts I sometimes ran into fiddlyness relating to parameter validation when using constructor chaining.

This is easiest to explain with a (contrived) example:

```
class Test
{
    public Test(int i)
    {
        if (i == 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("i", i, "i can't be 0");
    }

    public Test(string s): this(int.Parse(s))
    {
        if (s == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("s");
    }
}
```

I want the `Test(string)` constructor to chain the `Test(int)` constructor, and to do so I use `int.Parse()`.

Of course, `int.Parse()` doesn't like having a null argument, so if *s* is null it will throw before I reach the validation lines:

```
if (s == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("s");
```

which renders that check useless.

How to fix that? Well, I sometimes used to do this:

```
class Test
{
    public Test(int i)
    {
        if (i == 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("i", i, "i can't be 0");
    }

    public Test(string s): this(convertArg(s))
    {
    }

    static int convertArg(string s)
    {
        if (s == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("s");

        return int.Parse(s);
    }
}
```

That's a bit fiddly, and the stack trace isn't ideal when it fails, but it works.

Now, along come Code Contracts, so I start using them:

```
class Test
{
    public Test(int i)
    {
        Contract.Requires(i != 0);
    }

    public Test(string s): this(convertArg(s))
    {
    }

    static int convertArg(string s)
    {
        Contract.Requires(s != null);
        return int.Parse(s);
    }
}
```

All well and good. It works fine. But then I discover that I can do this:

```
class Test
{
    public Test(int i)
    {
        Contract.Requires(i != 0);
    }

    public Test(string s): this(int.Parse(s))
    {
        // This line is executed before this(int.Parse(s))
        Contract.Requires(s != null);
    }
}
```

And then if I do `var test = new Test(null)`, the `Contract.Requires(s != null)` is executed *before* `this(int.Parse(s))`. This means that I can do away with the `convertArg()` test altogether!

**So, on to my actual questions:**

- Is this behaviour documented anywhere?
- Can I rely on this behaviour when writing code contracts for chained constructors like this?
- Is there some other way I should be approaching this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The short answer

Yes, the behavior is documented in the definition of "precondition", and in how legacy verification (if/then/throw) without a call to `Contract.EndContractBlock` is handled.

If you don't want to use `Contract.Requires`, you can change your constructor to

```
public Test(string s): this(int.Parse(s))
{
    if (s == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("s");
    Contract.EndContractBlock();
}
```

### The long answer

When you place a `Contract.*` call in your code, you are not actually calling a member in the `System.Diagnostics.Contracts` namespace.  For example, `Contract.Requires(bool)` is defined as:

```
[Conditional("CONTRACTS_FULL")]
public static void Requires(bool condition) 
{
    AssertMustUseRewriter(ContractFailureKind.Precondition, "Requires"); 
}
```

`AssertMustUseRewriter` unconditionally throws a `ContractException`, so in absence of rewriting the compiled binary, the code will just crash if `CONTRACTS_FULL` is defined.  If it is not defined, the pre-condition is never even checked, as the call to `Requires` is omitted by the C# compiler due to the presence of the [`[Conditional]` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

### The Rewriter

Based off of the settings selected in the project properties, Visual Studio will define `CONTRACTS_FULL` and call `ccrewrite` to generate the appropriate IL to check the contracts at runtime.

Example contract:

```
private string NullCoalesce(string input)
{
    Contract.Requires(input != "");
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>() != null);

    if (input == null)
        return "";
    return input;
}
```

Compiled with `csc program.cs /out:nocontract.dll`, you get:

```
private string NullCoalesce(string input)
{
    if (input == null)
        return "";
    return input;
}
```

Compiled with `csc program.cs /define:CONTRACTS_FULL /out:prerewrite.dll` and run through `ccrewrite -assembly prerewrite.dll -out postrewrite.dll` you will get the code which will actually perform runtime checking:

```
private string NullCoalesce(string input)
{
    __ContractRuntime.Requires(input != "", null, null);
    string result;
    if (input == null)
    {
        result = "";
    }
    else
    {
        result = input;
    }
    __ContractRuntime.Ensures(result != null, null, null);
    return input;
}
```

Of prime interest is that our `Ensures` (a postcondition) got moved to the bottom of the method, and our `Requires` (a precondition) didn't really move since it was already at the top of the method.

This fits with the [documentation's definition](http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/2/7/C2715F76-F56C-4D37-9231-EF8076B7EC13/userdoc.pdf):

> [Preconditions] are contracts on the state of the world when a method is invoked.
>   ...
>   Postconditions are contracts on the state of a method when it terminates. In other words, the condition is checked just prior to exiting a method.

Now, the complexity in your scenario exists in the very definition of a precondition.  Based off of the definition listed above, the precondition runs *before* the method runs. The problem is that the C# specification says that the constructor initializer (chained constructor) must be invoked immediately before the constructor-body [[CSHARP 10.11.1]](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029), which is at odds with the definition of a precondition.

### Magic lives here

The code that `ccrewrite` generates cannot therefore be represented as C#, as the language provides no mechanism to run code before the chained constructor (except by calling static methods in the chained constructor parameter list as you mention).  `ccrewrite`, as required by the definition takes your constructor

```
public Test(string s)
    : this(int.Parse(s))
{
    Contract.Requires(s != null);
}
```

which gets compiled as

[image: the MSIL of the compiled code above]

and moves the call to requires to before the call to the chained constructor:

[image: the msil of the code above passed through the contract rewriter]

### Which means...

The way to avoid having to resort to static methods doing argument validation is to use the contract rewriter.  You can invoke the rewriter by using `Contract.Requires`, or by signifying that a block of code is a precondition by ending it with `Contract.EndContractBlock();`.  Doing so will cause the rewriter to place it at the start of the method, before the call to the constructor initializer.